# Populate second node reference based on what first node reference is selected

Tags: 7, nodes

I have 2 content types. Destinations content type and regions content type.  In regions content type i give reference to destinations node reference.

I am building another content type called product where i give node reference to Destinations and along with it i give node reference to regions content type.

My problem is that i need to filter out the regions(node reference to regions) drop down based on what destination is selected from previous destinations drop down.

So how do i do this ? please give me some idea for this. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Have you completed this task